# no database selected in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

When working on a file, I open and close connections like this:

```
require("../StoredProcedure/connect.php");//users.user_id 

 //..some query and code

mysql_close();
```

I do that multiple times for the whole file.. is it more efficient, to open the connection once instead and close it at the end of the file instead..

I also get the error message:

```
 No database selected
```

But I do require the connect file with teh database selected..why do I get that message?

That is what is inside the file:

```
<?
    $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error);
    mysql_select_db("politicalforum",$conn); 
?>
```

The connection works..I tried with other queries

Comment: You get the error message every time you connect or there are some situations?

Comment: can you post this connect.php file code?

Comment: no , in that particular situation only.. I think i have an imbalance between mysql_close() to mysql_connect()..but I am not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having multiple connections to a database in one program/instance and everytime you call

```
require('../StoredProcedure/connect.php');
```

The best policy for a database connection in a script is to call it the first time you need it and close it the last time you will use it. Basically at the top and bottom of the script.

On a side note:

```
include('../StoredProcedure/connect.php');
```

is faster than require and if you can use single quotes around everything. Your script will execute faster with less strain on your server resources.

Comment: so you are saying I dont lose speed by opening multiple connections in a script, rather than opening the connection once at the top of the script and closing it at the bottom of the script?

Comment: "called once per script a" - this is wrong. `require` is not `require_once`. Only difference between `include` and `require` is script will throw Fatal error and die if file not exists in require argument.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Good catch. It is late and i am tired. I have updated the post.

Comment: @WithFlyingColors The more files you include/require it will take longer for the script to run. On most newer servers it is not noticable with a few connections but when your site gets 1000's of hits a day it can make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion to you, is to move to PDO. The structure there is much more fitting for your kind of approach (multiple connections).

In addition (and not in contrast) to the above, I believe you should stick to a single connection **per database**. It is not required to open and close the connection each time as it will not save you any server resources or increase the speed of your script.

In PDO Database selection is already embedded in the connection DSN:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<SOMEDB>', '<USERNAME>', 'PASSWORD');
```

I urge you to learn it and move away from `mysql_*` functions as they have many problems (the most prominent one is not having **prepared statements**).

### Further Points

- Don't use PHP short tags (`<? ?>`). Use the full ones (`<?php ?>`), the old ones are deprecated and may be dropped in future projects.
- Indent your code properly, this alone solves many unseen problems (to indent large chunks of code here on StackOVerflow, paste your *already indented* code, highlight it, and then press the code button (or CTRL+K).)

Comment: +1, PHP programmers need to get away from escaping and move to prepared statements.

Comment: lol, I am a new programmer and thats what they teach me at school..after I gain some experience, I will move to PDO and ruby on rails

Comment: F*** school. Use PDO as early as possible. I'm telling you, it'll be better in the future.

Answer (score -1):

you can't do this:

```
mysql_close();
```

you should close your connection like this:

```
$link_identifier = mysql_connect(...);
mysql_close($link_identifier);
```

So in your case it will be

```
mysql_close($conn);
```

Anyways you don't need to close connection, PHP will do same when script ends.

And you shouldn't open & close connection many times in script. Just once (for example on top and bottom of script)

Comment: hmmm..never heard about such convention..mysql_close()..worked for me many times before without any parameters

Comment: @WithFlyingColors check this comment http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php#102544

Comment: @JamesWilliams check comment i mention above please

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski it does state that mysql_close() will not work with persistent connections only. I have used mysql_close() on php 5.3 servers with no issue.